# How do I import local fonts async?

Tags: html, css, asynchronous, fonts, webfonts

I have recently started hosting the few fonts I use for my website localy. Before I did that I was loading them from google fonts asyn to avoid loading blocking but now I'm not sure how to go about it.

Syntax in HTML before:

```
<link rel="import" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Titillium+Web:wght@300;400;600&display=swap" async>
```

Syntax in CSS after:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Titillium Web";
    src: url("../fonts/titillium-web-300.woff2") format('woff2');
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-style: normal;
    font-display: swap
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "Titillium Web";
    src: url("../fonts/titillium-web-400.woff2") format('woff2');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-display: swap
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "Titillium Web";
    src: url("../fonts/titillium-web-600.woff2") format('woff2');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
    font-display: swap
}
```

Just using swap still causes blocking(chaining critical requests):

[image]

so I need to load fully async like before somehow. I haven't found a way to load async in CSS and I'm not sure how to properly define the fonts while using HTML loading. What can I do?